# angular 2 for i= always 20 help me guys whats wrong here?

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-directives

you can see here my code its this console.log(parti+" "+ i); i always return 20 whats wrong my code just say it to me ı cant see please . thanks.

```js
        for(var i=0;i<=20;i++){
          this.http.get("https://tr1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/"+data.matches[i].gameId+"?api_key="+this.apikey).map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(data => {
for(var c=0;c<=9;c++){
  if  (data.participantIdentities[c].player.summonerName.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '')==ev.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '')){
    var parti=data.participantIdentities[c].participantId;
console.log(parti+" "+ i);

console.log(data.participants[parti-1].stats.win)

this.virtual.push({gameid: this.matches[i].gameId , champion: this.matches[i].champion,time : this.matches[i].timestamp,win:data.participants[parti-1].stats.win}) ;

}
  
}
console.log(data);

  });
        }
```

Comment: code is not async man

Comment: the for loop can't wait for the http request to complete since there is no blocking I/O.

Comment: This may be related to **async** operations. Here, your `for` loop doesn't wait for http request to complete & starts next iteration. This is what I think. If this is the case, you can use `promise`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to iterate http requests 20 times. Instead, send an array in a single request & handle it that way at your server side, so that you will get response as an array.

Comment: but ı cant reach the server its a api . ı just have a webservice link. its return array and ı need to work on that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data from the GET calls arrive, your callback functions will be called.
This, however, is after your code (including the loop) has run, so the value of `i` is 20.
The simplest way to solve this is to call a separate function from your outer loop and pass in the current index.
The function will capture that value as parameter which will be in scope when your callback is being run.

I.e.

```
for(var i=0;i<=20;i++) {
    getData(i);
 }

function getData(i) {
  this.http.get("https://tr1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/"+data.matches[i].gameId+"?api_key="+this.apikey).map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(data => {
for(var c=0;c<=9;c++){
  if  (data.participantIdentities[c].player.summonerName.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '')==ev.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '')){
    var parti=data.participantIdentities[c].participantId;
console.log(parti+" "+ i);

console.log(data.participants[parti-1].stats.win)

this.virtual.push({gameid: this.matches[i].gameId , champion: this.matches[i].champion,time : this.matches[i].timestamp,win:data.participants[parti-1].stats.win}) ;

}
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: can you accept my answer then?